# Why isnt else if statement working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

JavaScript

```
function AdultNumber(){              /* Ticket Number Validation   */  
    var AdInput = $("#adult").val();

    if (AdInput > 0 ){
        document.getElementById("AdTickError").textContent = "";
        return true;

    } else if( AdInput > 20) {
        confirm("You sure you want 20+ Passengers?");
        return true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("AdTickError").textContent = "Incorrect Enter Correct Number Of Passengers";
        return false;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<label for="Adult-ticket" class="center-label">Adults(+16)</label>
    <input type="number" id="adult" name="user_adult">
<label id = "AdTickError"></label>
```

Why does it not display confirm box if user inputs over 20? I want it that if user chooses 20 or over an confirm box prompts asking user if they want to continue.

Comment: One issue is that it will always hit the first if statement because anything greater than 20 is also greater than 0.  So it won't enter the else if statement.

Comment: i know it sounds crazy, but could it be the work of other wordly beings?

Comment: do you ever call the function AdultNumber?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to change this condition:

`if (AdInput > 0 )`

to this:

`if (AdInput > 0 && AdInput <= 20){`

Answer (score 1):

Values retrieved from DOM elements are always treated as strings. You need to say:

```
var AdInput = parseFloat($("#adult").val());
```

Or, depending on your needs, you may wanna use `parseInt()` instead of `parseFloat()` to get an integer not a float.

Comment: There is no "need" to  do this. The relational comparison operator (`>`) will implicitly convert the value to number anyway.

Comment: Not true, the comparison operator will treat the number as a string and will compare their lengths.

Comment: Y2H is right. Felix King you must be new to JS.

Comment: @Anarakanitach: You guys are joking right? Since when does the `>` compare the **length** of a string? If any, it compares the strings based on the lexicographical order. E.g. `"ab" < "b"` is `true`. According to you it should be `false`, since `"ab"` is "longer". However if you are comparing a number and a string, then the string is converted to a number. Example: `100 < "20"` is `false`. Consequently, `"200" > 0` is the same as `200 > 0`. No explicit type conversion required. See the spec: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-abstract-relational-comparison

Comment: Maybe this is a better example to convince you: `"20" < "100"` is `false`, but `"20" < 100` (or `20 < "100")` is `true`. The issue with the OP's code is just the order of conditions, not the data type of the values.

Comment: I’m sorry Felix but I just tried the code myself and, for instance, "10" is neither greater than nor smaller than 20. However, "10" is greater than 0. I just tested these scenarios myself. Maybe tomorrow I’ll start looking at the documentation regarding this part (if any exists).

Comment: Oh wait, OK my bad I’m so sorry I misspelled a number in my code. Apparently you were right after. Thanks for pushing me to figure this 1 out.